# Error finding handlbars file directory in Node Project

Tags: node.js, handlebars.js, nodemailer

I have the following folder and file structure in my Node project:

[image]

And the following configuration of email templates:

```
configureTemplates() {
    const viewPath = resolve(__dirname, '..', 'app', 'views', 'emails');

    this.transporter.use('compile', nodemailerhbs({
      viewEngine: exphbs.create({
        layoutsDir: resolve(viewPath, 'layouts'),
        partialsDir: resolve(viewPath, 'partials'),
        defaultLayout: 'default',
        extName: '.hbs',
      }),
      viewPath,
      extName: '.hbs',
    }));
  }
```

When I execute the method, the following error is displayed to me:

[image]

What's wrong ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. The `extname` property from `create` method is written all lowercase. Only the `extName` property of the `use` method is capitalized with the letter N.

```
configureTemplates() {
    const viewPath = resolve(__dirname, '..', 'app', 'views', 'emails');

    this.transporter.use('compile', nodemailerhbs({
      viewEngine: exphbs.create({
        layoutsDir: resolve(viewPath, 'layouts'),
        partialsDir: resolve(viewPath, 'partials'),
        defaultLayout: 'default',
        extname: '.hbs',
      }),
      viewPath,
      extName: '.hbs',
    }));
```